# Misaligned images when dynamically added

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, alignment

I'm populating tableViewCells with images from our server and when I profile my tableView with "**Color misaligned images**" I see that all my images are misaligned. 
The strange thing is that all images is within the right size from the beginning, 100px x 75px. They should fit perfectly in my tableCells imageView that has a fixed size of 100px x 75px.

If I try using a image from bundle I get **no** misalignment. So that tells me that all images on our server (saved with photoShop) is not **exactly** 100x75.

But that's so strange because when I log the image size before adding it to the imageView I get Width:100.000000 Height: 75.000000. That's very accurate if you ask me, but maybe not enough for iOS?

My other subviews in the cell are aligned. Note that I'm using interface builder to create my cell.

Can I get them aligned somehow?

thanks!

Comment: I guess your table view cell is 100x75 POINTS, whereas your image is 100x75 PIXELS? If you're on a retina device, the 100x75px image has to be scaled up to 200x150px in order to fit your image view.

Comment: @FlorianKugler You're right of course. Thanks! =) If you put your comment as answer I accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing misaligned images is that you're image is 100x75 pixels, whereas the image view is 100x75 points = 200x150 pixels (on a retina device). Therefore the image has to be scaled.

Using a proper @2x version of the image at 200x150 pixels will solve the problem.